# Ruby on Rails Carrierwave: ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Avatar can't be blank):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, carrierwave, rest-client

I am trying to integrate Carrierwave with an RoR API, and I encounter this error message:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Avatar can't be blank):
  app/controllers/api/v1/user_controller.rb:10:in `upload'
```

User controller:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class UserController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
      #before_filter :authenticate_user_from_token!

      def upload        
        @user = User.find_by(email: params[:user][:email])
        @user.avatar = params[:user][:file]
        @user.save!

        p @user.avatar.url # => '/url/to/file.png'
        p @user.avatar.current_path # => 'path/to/file.png'
        p @user.avatar_identifier # => 'file.png'
      end
...
```

The output for:

```
params[:user][:email] => user@email.com
params[:user][:file] => #<File:0x007fbacc083318>
```

The API call is performed using rest-client gem:

```
...
response = RestClient.post 'http://' + @host.to_s + ':' + @port.to_s + '/api/user/upload', {'user' => { 'email' => email, 'file' => File.new("/Users/admin/Desktop/me.jpg", 'rb')}}.to_json, :content_type => :json
...
```

I have a feeling that the post is not correct.

Many thanks !

Comment: you cannot store file himself, all u need to save is path. this is wrong `@user.avatar = params[:user][:file]`

Comment: Yes, this is true. I discovered that the request was not properly build (I was not using :multipart => true) This is my new request: request = RestClient::Request.new(
          :method => :post,
          :url => 'http://' + host.to_s + ':' + port.to_s + '/api/user/upload',
          :payload => {
            :multipart => true,
            :email => email,
            :file => file
          }, 
          :accept => accept.to_s)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, I am not exactly sure. Let me know!

```
  def upload        
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:user][:email])

    File.open(params[:user][:file]) do |f|
       @user.avatar = f
    end

    @user.save!
  end
```